# Unable to save data held in a variable - has no method 'set'

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

UPDATED.

This code block takes the users facebook connections and saves them into the "fbdata" and within the div "friends-list-container".

Here is the page with the error.

I'm then attempting to save the data to parse.com and have the following error shown the image below.

```
<!doctype html>

     <!-- Runs Parse and FB code that uses Facebook authentication to login 
user to the site and redirects them to the main content area. This page is
fired from the Facebook button being clicked on the site landing page-->


        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
            <meta name="description" content="fresh Gray Bootstrap 3.0 Responsive Theme "/>
            <meta name="keywords" content="Template, Theme, web, html5, css3, Bootstrap,Bootstrap 3.0 Responsive Login" />
            <meta name="author" content="Adsays"/>
            <title>Parse JavaScript Todo App</title>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/underscore-1.1.6.js"></script>
            <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.13.min.js"></script>



        </head>
        <body>

            <!-- Important, must be on the page -->
            <div id="fb-root"></div>    


            <!-- Initialize the Parse object-->
            <script type="text/javascript">     
            Parse.initialize("79tphN5KrDXdjJnAmehgBHgOjgE2dLGTvEPR9pEJ", "9lblofQNZlypAtveU4i4IzEpaOqtBgMcmuU1AE6Y");

            var user = Parse.User.current();
        //Fb app information//

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
                appId      : '523753101076577',
                channelUrl : 'http://www.kudosoo.com/channel.html',
                status     : true,
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true
            });

        //FB user authentication script, after this completes it fires todos_two.js to redirect user to main content page//


        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){
              if (response && response.data){
                var contact = new Parse.User();
                var fbdata=response.data;
                var divTarget=document.getElementById("friends-list-container");
              for (var friendIndex=0; friendIndex<fbdata.length; friendIndex++)
            {      var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
                   divContainer.innerHTML="<b>" + fbdata[friendIndex].name + "</b>";
                   divTarget.appendChild(divContainer);
            }

        var contact = new Parse.User();
        var contact = new Contact();



            $(document).ready(function () {
                         var username = $("#friends-list-container").val();
                         contact.set("facebookFriends", fbdata.toString());
                        contact.save(null, {
                            success: function (results) {
                                // The object was saved successfully.
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function (contact, error) {
                                // The save failed.
                                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                            }
                        });
                    });


              } else {
                console.log('Something goes wrong', response);
              }
            });

          }
        });



        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


        </script>
        <div id="friends-list-container"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Here is the error.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it be that `contact` doesn't have a `set` method?

Comment: @Hatsjoem Not sure I follow? is that not being done here? contact.set("facebookFriends", fbdata.toString()); can you give me an example?

Comment: look at the error, contact doesn't have a set method "Object contact has no method 'set'"

Comment: Ok, but I don't have the knowledge to resolve this, can you help? if you add to an answer and it works I can then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
var contact = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
```

Updated from the chat conversation, this is what solved the problem:

If you want to store the friends list in an array on the current user, then Parse.User.current() is what you want:

```
var contact = Parse.User.current()
```

Comment: Thank you, I was close then...I'm happy to accept this as the answer, if I can just resolve this part that's happening now. The page is returning POST https://api.parse.com/1/users 400 (Bad Request)  eror in dev tools. The actual page is here http://kudosoo.com/addfriends.html I'm not sure why it is asking for the password as the user is already logged in?

Comment: I'm not used to the JS API for Parse, but after a little checking it seems that the User class is special when it comes to extending it here as well. Check this link: https://parse.com/questions/extending-the-default-parse-user

Comment: In your use, the part I commented on, it doesn't seem you need to extend the User class like that. You are just trying to do ordinary stuff with it. I will edit my answer to what I think you need to do.

Comment: I made that change, but I get a Uncaught ReferenceError: Contact is not defined returned now from the http://kudosoo.com/addfriends.html page, perghaps variable is not correct? really sorry that this is dragging on...I really hope we can solve so I can give you the bounty ;-)

Comment: You need to use Captial C on the first Contact. See updated answer

Comment: I've done that now, but it returns the attached error "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" in the question above which can be seen in this link too http://kudosoo.com/addfriends.html

Comment: I am not getting that error from the page you linked. How are you getting it? Not only by clicking that link?

Comment: strange, I'm seeing that error when I use the google console log. I presume that you are not seeing it as you are not actually logged into the site using facebook? I can send you a link to the reg page if you like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51362/discussion-between-handsomeguy-and-dano007)