# Replicating parse.com anypic in JavaScript - Unable to compare Fb users

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com to build the back end of my app. I want the user to be able to find their friends that are using my app and who they are friends with on Facebook.

I'm using JavaScript, however unlike IOS, here https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anypic#follow there are no examples on how to build the app

I have used the Fb SDK to pull back a users friend connections, but I'm stumped on how to proceed next.

I guess I need to run a query between the returned data and my current users data and look for matches and then return them?

Has any one experience doing this? can share some code or point me in the direction of external resources?

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){
      if (response && response.data){
            for (var friendIndex=0; friendIndex<data.length; friendIndex++)

      } else {
        console.log('Something goes wrong', response);
      }
    });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this reliably, which has nothing to do with language, is a multi-step process:

**One**: Provide a way to "connect to facebook". In this process, you pull the user's facebook id and store it as a field on the user profile in parse. This is the field you need to match friends.

You will only be able to reliably match the user's friends who has ALSO CONNECTED THEIR APP TO FACEBOOK (and thereby stored their facebook id in their user profile).

**Two**: Perform a query against Parse with the user's friends' facebook IDs. For every friend facebook id you find in your Parse user database, you display their name etc FROM FACEBOOK (so they recognize them easily).

This means that when you add this functionality, nobody will find their friends from facebook in their app. Only when some of their friends connect to facebook will they be able to find facebook friends like this.

You can i.e. check for this on app launch, and then notify the user that some of their facebook friends are now using your app.

Comment: I've accepted the answer as I think this is the best response I can get. The steps you have described above are what I was attempting to do. However I've reached a block due to an error message I cant solve as described in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167565/unable-to-save-data-held-in-a-variable-has-no-method-set?noredirect=1#comment35429801_23167565 Many thanks for the help :-)